# JsonObjectRequest always return empty Objects

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'm developing a MediaPlayer for streaming Music but recently I'm stuck.

When I request a JSONObject, I receive it but it's empty (the Log show me that). I tried with JSONArray and it's the same result (all my code is below).

My PHP seems good because I tried it with an http tester for the POST request and it always return the good result. The SharedPreferences is neither in cause.

I really can't understand where is the problem so thanks for all help :D

***MY REQUEST METHOD:***

```
  private void SelectAlbum() {
    //Getting values from edit texts
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.ALBUM_SELECTED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    chxAlbum = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.ALBUM_SELECTED, "Preview");
    //Creating a string request
    JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL
            , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("test", response.toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yeees!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put(Config.KEY_ALBUM, chxAlbum);
            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

***MY PHP CODE:***

```
 <?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $album= $_POST['album'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbMusique WHERE album LIKE '$album' ";

  require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $result = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 array_push($result,
 array(

 '0'=>$row[0],
 '1'=>$row[1],
 '2'=>$row[2],
 '3'=>$row[3],
 '4'=>$row[4],
 '5'=>$row[5],
 '6'=>$row[6],
 '7'=>$row[7],
 '8'=>$row[8],
 '9'=>$row[9],

  ));
 }
 $final = json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

 echo stripslashes($final);
 }
```

***MY LOG:***

```
 6-07 16:16:36.600 11985-11985/com.example.pierr.puremusictest2 D/test: {"result":[]}
```

***AND FINALLY THE RESULT FROM HTTP TESTER:***

```
 {"result":[["2","5","Satellite","Capital Kings","II",null,"2015","http://www.jesusfreakhideout.com/cdreviews/covers/capitalkingsii.jpg","http://lolilol.890m.com/Musique/CapitalKings/II/Capital_Kings_-_Satellites_Official_Audio_Video-r8.aac",null]]}
```

Comment: The edit history here indicates you deleted and undeleted this 7 hours ago - just do a delete again? Please do not replace your posts with "delete this" though - this just creates work for editors. Thanks.

Comment: yeah but nobody saw my question and now i'm alone so, what should i do?

Comment: If you still need an answer, then carry on doing your research and edit your new findings at the end. Please do not delete and repost - improve it instead. The question is only 16 hours old, so it is a bit early to think no-one will answer - you've had 25 views. Unfortunately, since this site is mostly populated by volunteers, we cannot guarantee that every question will get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Be careful with `$album` - that has a SQL injection vulnerability in it at present. Your `LIKE` is just doing `=` at present, did you mean to add wildcards in there?

Comment: ok no probelm thaks you for the help! sorry for the problem i caused you

Comment: Ok thanks you i gonna see how i can change that injection vulnerabilty for the futur :D

Comment: Search for "php mysqli parameter binding" to find out how! No problems `:-)`.